# QProgressBar busy indicator stuttering when custom style sheet is applied

Tags: windows, pyqt, pyqt4

As the title states, once I apply a style sheet the busy indicator is very noticeably stuttering at maybe 10 fps. The default windows style works fine, as does similar code using C++ and native Qt.

```
class LoadDialog(QtGui.QDialog, loaddialog_ui):
  def __init__(self, title, text, minimum, maximum, start, parent=None):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window | QtCore.Qt.WindowTitleHint | QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)

    self.progressBar.setMinimum(minimum)
    self.progressBar.setMaximum(maximum)
    self.progressBar.setValue(start)
    self.setWindowTitle(title)
    self.labelText.setText(text)
    self.progressBar.setStyleSheet("QProgressBar::chunk { background: solid black; }")

dialog = LoadDialog("Title", "Text", 0, 0, 0)
dialog.exec_()
```